# I want to enter text in search text box and click search icon or enter

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, xpath, chromedriver, waits

I am facing the issue . Kindly assist.
The HTML Code snippet is attached

I am getting the error as [image]

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@id='search']"}

## The code

```
//click login button
    driver.findElement(By.id("save_sla")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    WebElement wb=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='search']"));
        
    WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,30);

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(wb)).sendKeys("xyz");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//i[@id='search001a']")).click();
```

[image]

Comment: The highlighted line in the screenshot is not relevant to the Exception occurred. Please check.

Comment: @kaweeshaThe xpath provided is able to find the element but when i execute the code it shows "noElementFoundException"   By.xpath("//input[@id='search']"

Comment: I also tried with css selector By.cssSelector("#search"). But still getting "noElementFoundException"

Comment: NoSuchElementException can be occurred due to many reasons. Refer the accepted answer in here; [NoSuchElementException, Selenium unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471321/nosuchelementexception-selenium-unable-to-locate-element/48472940#48472940). Without looking at the complete DOM its difficult to understand a reason. If you are okay, share the page URL.

Comment: @kaweesha ..issue caused by the page not completely loaded when I find the element.Now i added more delay which i never expected and issue is resolved .Thanks for your suggestions and time

Comment: Element was being identified before the elements loaded .Hence i was getting error

Answer (score 0):

You must be getting the wrong input tag. You're locating the search box with  //input[@id='search'], I guess what you need is //input[@id='search_submit'].